# How to split up typescript definition into multiple files?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like my typescript definition file to be split up similar to how my library is split up currently. I have a folder called api where all the services live and then a folder called model where all the models live like so:

`api
    ServiceOne
    ServiceTwo
    etc..
models
    ModelOne
    ModelTwo
    etc...`

I came across `reference path` which I think is what I'm looking for but I can't quite get it to do what I want. Here's how i'm using it:

```
/// <reference path="./models/AccessToken.d.ts" />

declare module 'ordercloud-javascript-sdk' {
  namespace Auth { function Testing(a: string): string; }
}
```

The reference path has a model for AccessToken. However when I try to do:

```
import { AccessToken } from 'ordercloud-javascript-sdk`
```

I get 'has no exported member AccessToken' error. Meanwhile when I define it like this:

```
declare module 'ordercloud-javascript-sdk' {
  namespace Auth {
    function Testing(a: string): string;
  }
  interface AccessToken {
    token: string;
  }
}
```

it works great, but I lose out on being able to organize my definition in the way i want. I'm not sure how to reference something but say "make it a part of this module". Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `export` in your module to export from the referenced file?

Comment: Hmm so I wouldn't be able to just reference an interface? It would need to be part of a module? I'd like all my models/services to be part of one module (the one that's being declared). Maybe there's a way to merge them?

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but The referenced file inside the module would be a private reference.  In order to make anything in that reference public you would have to export it (inside your module) so that it becomes public to anything that imports that module.  I'm not saying this would work at all, just my thoughts.